# Exchange RPC CAS won't start

Tags: exchange-2010, rpc

This weekend Exchange 2010 stopped working with Outlook clients.
Researching the problem I found out that the **Exchange RPC Client Access Service** is not starting.
Looking at the event log this is what I get:

**Message:** Failed to register service principal name ExchangeMDB.  Failed with error code The specified account does not exist (1317).

**Source:** MSExchangeRPC

**Event ID:** 1002

I already checked for ExchangeMDB and its is registered in AD pointing to the right box.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: First of all, check SPN's for the CAS server: from an elevated command prompt run `setspn -L [CAS Server name]`. Second, try to change the Log On as account for the RPC Client Access Service to LocalSystem and try to start it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was not related to any Exchange functionality. It seems a GPO was changed  for the OU containing the exchange server account and Network Servive or Local System were having problems starting the service.
We have moved the server to a different OU and the problem is gone.

I will try to update on what in GPO was affecting those accounts later.